# Jquery auto selecting select option problem when option not available

Tags: jquery, select

New to Jquery here as the question might suggest..

I have 2 selects, and their numeric options are generated by php, where the two ranges are often differect, e.g. first one is 0-7, and the second one is 0-4.

When the user selects a number in the first select, I need that value to be auto selected in the second select, and I do that with the code below.

The problem is that, when the option is not available in the second select, e.g. 5, 6 or 7, nothing will be selected, which would not be a problem however it seems to break something because when this is the case, the form can not be submitted, just nothing happens.

I am therefore trying to think of a solution where Jquery detects that the option is not available and selects 0, instead of nothing.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select1").change(function () {
    var list1 = $(this).val();
    $('#select2').val(list1).change();
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the second select contains an option with the value of the selected option of the first select using [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select1").change(function() {
    var list1 = $(this).val();
    if ($("#select2 option[value='" + list1 + "']").length > 0) {
      $("#select2").val(list1).change();
    } else {
      $("#select2").val("0").change();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```